# scheduled task response to channel spring-integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

How can I pass a response from task:scheduled in spring-intgeration to a channel?

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="loadFruits" method="loadFruits" cron="0/5 * * * * *"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>  
<bean id="loadFruits" class="com.data.taskschedulers.LoadFruits"/>
<int:channel id="outboundComplexChannel"/>
```

Now can I some how read the return response of loadFruits method to a channel outboundComplexChannel

Please provide if any way of doing this

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an inbound-channel-adapter instead

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter ref="loadfruits" method="loadFruits"
        channel="outboundComplexChannel">
    <int:poller cron="0/5 * * * * *"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: <int:poller cron="0/5 * * * * *"/> a small typo :)